# Python packages install error for EnMap-BOX 3.0, QGIS plugin

Tags: python, plugins, gis, qgis, enmap

I'm new, this is my first question here, I hope I'm not messing it up. I am running Windows 11 home, v10.0.22621. I have QGIS installed and Python too (see below for versions). I have been trying to install EnMap for QGIS. After the plugin installation, I clicked on "install Python missing packages", but I got this error when I let the installation process run:

**subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.0\apps\Python39\python3.exe -m pip list' returned non-zero exit status 1.**

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.0\apps\Python39\python3.exe -m pip list' returned non-zero exit status 1. 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users/agoag/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\enmapboxplugin\enmapbox\gui\enmapboxgui.py", line 806, in showPackageInstaller
    w.addPackages(requiredPackages())
  File "C:\Users/agoag/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\enmapboxplugin\enmapbox\dependencycheck.py", line 1043, in addPackages
    self.loadPIPVersionInfo(packages)
  File "C:\Users/agoag/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\enmapboxplugin\enmapbox\dependencycheck.py", line 974, in loadPIPVersionInfo
    self.startTask(task)
  File "C:\Users/agoag/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\enmapboxplugin\enmapbox\dependencycheck.py", line 989, in startTask
    qgsTask.run()
  File "C:\Users/agoag/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\enmapboxplugin\enmapbox\dependencycheck.py", line 292, in run
    process = subprocess.run(cmdList,
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 528, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.0\apps\Python39\python3.exe -m pip list' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Python version: 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.28.0-Firenze Firenze, ed3ad0430f3 
Python path:
C:\Users\agoag\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\enmapboxplugin\enmapbox\apps\ensomap
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.0/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/agoag/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/agoag/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.0\bin\python39.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.0\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/agoag/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:\Users\agoag\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows
C:\Users/agoag/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\enmapboxplugin\site-packages
C:\Users/agoag/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\enmapboxplugin
C:\Users\agoag\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\enmapboxplugin\enmapbox\qgispluginsupport\qps\pyqtgraph
C:\Users\agoag\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\enmapboxplugin\enmapbox\site-packages
C:\Users\agoag\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\enmapboxplugin\enmapbox\apps
C:\Users\agoag\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\enmapboxplugin\enmapbox\coreapps
C:\Users\agoag\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\enmapboxplugin\enmapbox\eo4qapps
.
```

I went through some questions found here, and I came up with opening the cmd as admin and running the following code:

`pip install --upgrade setuptools`
`python setup.py install --no DLIB_GIF_SUPPORT`

Now for the first line (`pip install --upgrade setuptools`) it was fine, I saw I had updates to install and I did, the process was fine.

For the second line (`python setup.py install --no DLIB_GIF_SUPPORT`) I get this error

```
**C:\Windows\System32>python setup.py install --no DLIB_GIF_SUPPORT 
python: can't open file 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory**
```

How can I solve this?
I am very new at coding, so I ask your patience. I hope the question was explained as needed. If you need any other information, I can try to provide it.

Comment: python package manager is here https://pypi.org/project/pip.  I have not come across this module (QGIS) before but you can search for that module on the pypi website.