# EnMAP-Box3 (3.13.2) installation error in QGIS version 3.28.9-Firenze

Tags: python, plugins, qgis

After clicking on install missing packages in the tool, I still get the following error. How to fix it? I want this plug-in to work. Its not working.

```
An error has occurred while executing Python code: 
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.9\apps\Python39\python3.exe -m pip list' returned non-zero exit status 1. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users/rena.shereef/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\enmapboxplugin\enmapbox\gui\enmapboxgui.py", line 807, in showPackageInstaller
    w.addPackages(requiredPackages())
  File "C:\Users/rena.shereef/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\enmapboxplugin\enmapbox\dependencycheck.py", line 1043, in addPackages
    self.loadPIPVersionInfo(packages)
  File "C:\Users/rena.shereef/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\enmapboxplugin\enmapbox\dependencycheck.py", line 974, in loadPIPVersionInfo
    self.startTask(task)
  File "C:\Users/rena.shereef/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\enmapboxplugin\enmapbox\dependencycheck.py", line 989, in startTask
    qgsTask.run()
  File "C:\Users/rena.shereef/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\enmapboxplugin\enmapbox\dependencycheck.py", line 292, in run
    process = subprocess.run(cmdList,
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.9\apps\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 528, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.9\apps\Python39\python3.exe -m pip list' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Python version: 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.28.9-Firenze Firenze, 66f4d63ad4
```

Comment: Could be a duplicate of _unanswered_ question [install error for EnMap-BOX 3.0, QGIS plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77524383/21350362).

Comment: There is also an open bug: https://github.com/EnMAP-Box/enmap-box/issues/760

Answer (score 0):

In the dependency python file, look for these lines.

1. `args.append(str(localPythonExecutable()) + ' -m pip')`
2. `cmdList = str(localPythonExecutable()) + ' -m pip list'`

and replace them with the below code:

1. `args.append('\"'+str(localPythonExecutable()) +'\"' + ' -m pip')`
2. `cmdList = '\"' + str(localPythonExecutable()) + '\"' + ' -m pip list'`

After that, follow the instructions provided in this website:
[https://enmap-box.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usr_section/usr_installation.html#install-required-python-packages][1]

This has worked for me.